# Right way of using Django QueryDict in some function

Tags: python, json, django, unicode, request

I'm currently using code as follows:

```
# app/views.py    
def get_data(request):
  data = request.GET
  return Response(my_function(**data))

# utils/my_functions.py
import requests

def my_function(value1_int, value2_int, value_float, name_in_unicode):
  url = 'https://service.receiver.com/SomeMethod.aspx/GetInfo'
  data = {'value1_int': method1,
          'value2_int': method2,
          'velue_float': value_float,
          'name_in_unicode': name-in_unicode}
  r = requests.get(url, data)
  return r.json()
```

1. What is the right way to handle unicode characters?
2. I have a feeling that this sample of code is a complete disaster,
   but don't know exactly why
3. Should I sanitize input somehow, or throwing an exception is enough?
4. This sample works as expected, but I think I should convert
   QueryData to QueryData.dict(), but why if it works?
5. Maybe some advices, I didn't found anything about how to handle this
   in `2scoopss of django` book, or even in `djangoproject.com`.

Thanks a lot.